# Is it possible to repeat file_get_html() in a php loop?

Tags: php, mysql, dom

I am having some trouble with a fairly simple scraping program. Hopefully the working parts help someone set up a news aggregator if they're interested. I like to get specific stuff so I find grabbing the content and filtering by keywords helps me avoid the annoying issue of headlines about things that don't pertain to my life.

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions you all might have. This one has been bugging me for a couple days and I haven't come across a good solution.

Basically, the program fetches a set of items from a table to move to another table, and in the process should take the URL component of the table entry from table A that it is currently processing, and calls another program using the include. Program B uses it to grab content from that entry and save it to a file, which is named based on other attributes of the current item from table A.

The file is then saved to a folder, and the dom variable from program B is cleared so that the loop can continue.

Here is program A:

```
<?php
$db = 'newsfeed';
$zeta = 0;
$beta = 0;
// connect to RDS instance MySQL Database Newsfeed
include_once('/var/www/dbfunctions/mysqli_connectdb.php');

// set content source table 
$sourcetable = 'feedsources';
$mastertable = 'mastertable';

// set date to remove results older than
date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
$datenow = date_timestamp_get(date_create());
$offset = "86400";
$deldate = $datenow - $offset;

//begin cycling through content data

//delete all "old" entries from the mastertable

//get number of source items present
$itemquery = "SELECT id,name FROM $sourcetable";
$itemresult = mysqli_query($conn, $itemquery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemresult)) {
$sourceid = $row['id'];
$sourcename = $row['name'];

        // cycle throught the data tables 
        $dataquery = "SELECT * FROM $sourcetable WHERE id = $sourceid;";

        $dataresult = mysqli_query($conn, $dataquery);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dataresult)) {
        $table = $row['datatable'];
        }

        // copy all data from the targetted table into the master table 

        //loop through the targetted table and copy to mysql
        $getdata = "SELECT * FROM ".$table.";";
     $datareturn = mysqli_query($conn, $getdata);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datareturn)) {
                $date = $row['datecreated'];
                $title = addslashes($row['title']);
                $url = addslashes($row['url']);
                $tags = addslashes($row['tags']);
                $titleid = $row['id'];

        //get content and place in html file in /var/www/html/nuzr/content/



                //check whether the item already exists in the table
                $checkquery = "select id from ".$mastertable." where title = '".$title."';";

                $checkcheck = mysqli_query($conn, $checkquery);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($checkcheck) > 0){

                }else{

        require_once("getcontent.php");

                $copy = "INSERT INTO ".$mastertable." VALUES ('NULL','$table','$sourcename','$date','$title','$url','$tags','$filename');";
                mysqli_query($conn, $copy);

                echo "Beta is ".$beta;
                $beta = $beta + 1;
                        }
                }
        // clean the master table
        $delquery = 'DELETE FROM '.$mastertable.' WHERE datecreated < '.$deldate.';';

        mysqli_query($conn, $delquery);

}

function clear()
{
    $this->dom = null;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->parent = null;
    $this->children = null;
}

?>
```

Program B

```
<?php
//Check Start
//echo "Program Starts";

// Include the library
include('/var/www/tools/dom/simple_html_dom.php');

$source = $url;
$content = array();
$header1 = array();
$header2 = array();
$i = 0; $y = 0;

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html($source);

        //grab headers in case initial title is a header
        foreach($html->find('h1') as $e){

                $header1[$i] = $e->outertext;

                //echo $e->outertext;

                $i = $i + 1;
        }

        $i = 0;

        foreach($html->find('h2') as $e){

                $header2[$i] = $e->outertext;

                //echo $e->outertext;

                $i = $i + 1;
        }

        //reset counter
        $i = 0;

        // Find all paragraph tags and print their content into a text file
        foreach($html->find('p') as $e){

                $content[$i] = $e->outertext;

                //echo $e->outertext;

                $i = $i + 1;
        }

//create the content storage file
$filename = "/var/www/html/nuzr/content/".$table.$titleid.".html";
echo "The filename is".$filename;
        $file = fopen($filename,"a");

// write header and link to original article
$titleblurb = "<b>Original article courtesy of <a href='".$url."'>".$sourcename."</a></b>";
fwrite($file, $titleblurb);

// set site specific parameters based on header / footer size
if($sourcename == "The Globe and Mail"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 13; $y = 2;

        //Add Header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        $text = $header2[1];
        fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "CNN Money"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 3; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        $text = $header2[1];
        fwrite($file, $text);



}elseif($sourcename == "CNN Markets"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 3; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        //$text = $header2[1];
        //fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "BBC Business"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 9; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        //$text = $header2[1];
        //fwrite($file, $text);

}elseif($sourcename == "BBC Politics"){

//Set indexing parameters
$z = $i - 0; $y = 1;

        //Add header content
        $text = $header1[0];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        //$text = $header2[1];
        //fwrite($file, $text);

}else{
echo $sourcename;
}

        do{

        $text = $content[$y];
        fwrite($file, $text);
        $y = $y +1;

        }while($y<$z);

echo "Zeta is".$zeta;
$zeta = $zeta +1;

//close the content file
fclose($file);

//echo "File end.";

$html->clear();
unset($html);





?>
```

So long story short when I run this with all these output echos as update points it appears that the include(program B) only runs the first iteration and then it stops running. I was getting an issue with the file_get_html() until I added the clear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place the code from PROGRAM B inside

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datareturn)) {
        fetchURL($url);
    }
```

so that for every entry, when you have the $url, you can invoke program B. I suggest placing PROGRAM B as function and calling that function within the while loop.

something like this

```
function fetchURL($url) {
    // Place PROGRAM B here. You can make the `include` be part of the program A at the top.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Phreak!

Hmm... so I would have to add the whole source list from sql as an array and then download the files, save the names as another array, and then add the entries to sql?

It seems like there should be a more efficient way to do that :P

I was doing one by one parsing before to keep the memory use a bit lower. any thoughts?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please take a look. I did not notice your while loop before.